# Req.session is undefined inside request?

Tags: node.js, express

I am using request module in one of my application. I am trying to rewrite the request session maxAge value in the request response. However, it is not working. How to make req.session to be defined inside the request response/

```
function testFunction (req, res) {
    req.session.cookie.maxAge = 10000; // working

    request(option, function(err, response, body, req) {
        req.session.cookie.maxAge = body.maxAge; // session is undefined
    })
}

module.exports = {
    testFunction: testFunction
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're shadowing the original `req` variable. Rename one of them so that they don't conflict. For example:

```
request(option, function(err, response, body, req_) {
    req.session.cookie.maxAge = body.maxAge; // session is undefined
})
```

Or just remove that parameter entirely:

```
request(option, function(err, response, body) {
    req.session.cookie.maxAge = body.maxAge; // session is undefined
})
```

Comment: Hi, the session is defined now but unfortunately the new session value is not being set into mongodb. It does work if `req.session.cookie.maxAge` is outside of request

Answer (score 0):

The `request` operation here is an asynchronous behavior. You might need to put your db operation inside the `request` callback.

Or revise the `testFunction` to act asynchronously too. For example, return a Promise, etc.